# How to use lag function inside a pyspark agg function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to use `lag` function inside `agg` function. My data is as follow:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [
    ('a', 10, 15),
    ('a', 40, 60),
    ('a', 70, 100),
    ('b', 10, 20),
    ('b', 30, 50),
    ('b', 60, 80)
    ]
schema = ['id', 'start', 'end']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
```

I want to calculate the sum of difference of current start and previous end. Expected result:

```
a: (40 - 15) + (70 - 60) = 35
b: (30 - 20) + (60 - 50) = 20
```

This is what I have tried:

```
def duration(start, end):
    end_lag = lag(end, 1).over(Window.orderBy(end))    # <--- error
    d = start - end_lag
    return sum(d)

df.groupBy('id').agg(duration(col('start'), col('end'))).show()
```

But it shows an error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: It is not allowed to use a window function inside an aggregate function. Please use the inner window function in a sub-query.
```

Is there any way I can put `lag` function inside a `agg` function?

Comment: you could get the lags beforehand and then aggregate

Comment: @samkart But that's not very elegant since I have several other data frames calling this function. So I want to write `lag` function inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataFrame (df_1):

```
+---+-----+---+
| id|start|end|
+---+-----+---+
|  a|   10| 15|
|  a|   40| 60|
|  a|   70|100|
|  b|   10| 20|
|  b|   30| 50|
|  b|   60| 80|
+---+-----+---+
```

Necessary imports

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, lag, col, sum, row_number
```

1. If you need the `duration()` function to be used by some other DataFrames, better pass your DataFrame, group, start, and end column to this function. Then perform the necessary transformation inside it.

```
def duration(df_1, group_col, start_col, end_col):
    
    lag_spec = Window.orderBy(lit(1))
    row_spec = Window.partitionBy(group_col).orderBy(lit(0))

    # a. Use the lag() function to get the previous end column values
    df_2 = df_1.withColumn("prev_end", lag(end_col,1,0).over(lag_spec))
    
    # b. Add a row numbers to each `ID` helps in removing top record
    df_3 = df_2.withColumn("row", row_number().over(row_spec))
    
    # c. Remove top record and unwanted columns
    df_4 = df_3.filter("row > 1").drop(end_col, "row")

    # d. Aggregation part    
    df_5 = df_4.withColumn("result", col(start_col)-col("prev_end"))

    return df_5.groupBy(group_col).agg(sum("result").alias("result"))
```

2. Chain this function using `transform()` with the DataFrames you want

```
df_1.transform(lambda df: duration(df, "id", "start", "end")).show()
```

***Output:***

```
+---+------+
| id|result|
+---+------+
|  a|    35|
|  b|    20|
+---+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can you pack all those inside the aggregation function `duration()`? This function will be used by other data frame, so I would also like to avoid using `withColumn`

Comment: I have updated my answer, please let me know if changes needed.